# Why SetDelayed won't work

Tags: list-manipulation, syntax

I'm trying to do this:

```
Riffle[list = {a, b, c, d, e, f}, tem = RandomInteger[1, Length@list-1]]
```

> {a, 0, b, 0, c, 1, d, 0, e, 0, f}

But I think this method is too verbose. I don't want to count the length. So I want to do it like this:

```
Riffle[{a, b, c, d, e, f}, x := RandomInteger[1]]
```

And get this:

> {a, Null, b, Null, c, Null, d, Null, e, Null, f}

Or we use `RuleDelayed`:

```
Riffle[{a, b, c, d, e, f}, x :> RandomInteger[1]]
```

> {a,1:>RandomInteger[1],b,1:>RandomInteger[1],c,1:>RandomInteger[1],d,1:>RandomInteger[1],e,1:>RandomInteger[1],f}

What's wrong with my solution? How can I do this without counting the length?

Comment: `Riffle[list, x] /. x :> RandomInteger[1]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question has been answered by [garej](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/24604/garej) in his [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/111424/why-setdelayed-wont-work#comment302417_111424) and by [C. E.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/731/c-e), but in case you are interested in an alternative solution which does not involve `RuleDelayed` and is in the spirit of evaluation control, you could do

```
Riffle[{a, b, c, d, e, f}, Unevaluated@RandomInteger[1]]

(* {a, 0, b, 1, c, 0, d, 0, e, 1, f} *)
```

`Unevaluated` prevents temporarily the evaluation of `RandomInteger[1]`, so that the list is riffled with `RandomInteger[1]` verbatim. The intermediate step of the above evaluation is therefore:

```
(* {a, RandomInteger[1], b, RandomInteger[1], c, 
       RandomInteger[1], d, RandomInteger[1], e, RandomInteger[1], f} *)
```

(as the `Trace` shows). Each `RandomInteger` will then evaluate.

Comment: I don't know how to express my exciting when the first glance for your answer..You touch my G-point.

Comment: @yode I'm glad you find it useful. Thanks for the accept!

Answer (score 11):

`Riffle` does not have the `HoldAll` or `HoldRest` attribute:

```
Attributes[Riffle]
```

> `{Protected}`

The documentation for `SetDelayed` says that

> lhs:=rhs returns Null if the assignment specified can be performed,
>   and returns $Failed otherwise.

So what happens in your first example is that the second argument evaluates to `Null` before it is passed to `Riffle`.

Your second example is expected because `RuleDelayed` has the `HoldRest` attribute, which means that the second argument (`RandomInteger[1]`) is held. `x` evaluates to whatever value it has (`1`) because `RuleDelayed` does not have the `HoldFirst` or `HoldAll` attribute.

garej offers a good solution in his comment. Use an undefined symbol and `ReplaceAll`:

```
Riffle[list, x] /. x :> RandomInteger[1]
```

Comment: Good explaination.Thanks a lot.